# How to cohexist lombok and JPAMetalModel processors with maven

Tags: java, maven, jpa, lombok

How to use [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) when JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor annotation processor is activated in the maven build.

Maven config:

```
[...]
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <processor>org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor</processor>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
[...]
```

During the build process (mvn clean install), MetaModel objects are generated correctly but it seems the Lombok Annotation processor is not added into the Javac compilation anymore. All @Getter, @Setter,... doesn't work.

Comment: Which version of Java are you using? As far as I know, Lombok has problems with working with Java 8.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

After a look into the lombok project I found a solution.

When specifying the JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor as javac annotation processor, the lombok processor seems to be removed.

To correct this, we can simply add the Lombok annotation processor in the maven-compiler-plugin:

```
[...]
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <compilerArguments>
            <processor>org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor,lombok.launch.AnnotationProcessorHider$AnnotationProcessor</processor>
        </compilerArguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
[...]
```

Comment: Adding Lombok like this also works for the `maven-processor-plugin`.

Comment: Gave me an idea to find hidden lombok annotation and put at as another annotation processor under plugin > configuration > annotationProcessors > annotationProcessor. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 14):

The solution of @Pierrick is right. but I can offer this solution. because we can add many processors with this.

```
<plugin>
   <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
   <configuration>
      <annotationProcessorPaths>
         <path>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
         </path>
         <path>
             <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
             <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
             <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
         </path>
      </annotationProcessorPaths>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 3):

The Solution if @Pierrick is not totally correct. You have to switch the order of the processors.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <compilerArguments>
            <processor>
                lombok.launch.AnnotationProcessorHider$AnnotationProcessor,org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor
            </processor>
        </compilerArguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```