# Gradle, Lombok & JPAMetalModel processors: Project doesn't compile (package lombok doesn't exist)

Tags: jpa, gradle, lombok

Im using lombok in my gradle project and want to create a jar file but everytime im executing the jar task (no matter if triggered in my console or eclipse ide) im getting the error that my lombok imports cant be found in those classes where im using lombok annotations. Example output:

```
... other lombok related error messages ...

/test/entity/geo/Region.java:11: error: package lombok does not exist
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
             ^
/test/entity/geo/Region.java:12: error: package lombok does not exist
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
             ^
/test/entity/geo/Region.java:37: error: cannot find symbol
@Data
 ^
  symbol: class Data
100 errors
 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJpaModelgen'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

After searching a while i found out there is a plugin for gradle and lombok but isn't really needed for compiling with newer gradle versions. My gradle version is 3.4.1 and lombok 1.6.18.

In [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31805327/how-to-cohexist-lombok-and-jpametalmodel-processors-with-maven) i found probably a similar error but with maven.
I would like to try this in my build.gradle but i dont have an idea how to write/define this...

Starting and running my spring boot app withing my Eclipse ide works fine; only the gradle compileJava task seems to have a problem with lombok while compiling.

This is my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories { 
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies { classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:+") }
}

plugins { 
    id 'at.comm_unity.gradle.plugins.jpamodelgen' version '1.1.3'
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'at.comm_unity.gradle.plugins.jpamodelgen'
apply plugin: 'war'

war {
    baseName = 'test'
    version =  '0.0.1'
}

repositories { mavenCentral() }

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {

    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest"
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    compile"org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test"
    compile 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.1.1'
    compile 'javax.validation:validation-api:2.0.0.CR2'
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-java8:5.2.10.Final'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.8.9'
    compileOnly('javax.servlet:jstl')
    compile('org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat')
    compileOnly group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: '1.16.18'
    compile "com.google.guava:guava"
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.5'
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}

sourceSets {
    generated { java.srcDir "${buildDir}/generated/src/java/" }
}

ext['hibernate.version'] = '5.2.10.Final'


jpaModelgen {
    library = "org.hibernate:hibernate-jpamodelgen:5.2.10.Final"
    jpaModelgenSourcesDir = "src/generated/java"
}

compileJava.options.compilerArgs += ["-proc:none"]
```

Answer (score 0):

compileJava.options.compilerArgs += [
        "-proc:only",
]